# Get sum of amount fields result in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
    amount1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    amount2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    amount3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Amount
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_amount1(self,obj):
        """very large calculation here"""
        return 5

    def get_amount2(self,obj):
        """very large calculation here"""
        return 10

    def get_amount3(self,obj):
        """very large calculation here"""
        return 15

    def get_total(self,obj):
        return self.get_amount1 +self.get_amount2+self.get_amount3
```

Now I want to show the sum of all three amounts in `total` field, but it is taking too much time because of a large calculation in above methods and they are calculating twice only for getting `total`.

How can I get the sum of `amount1`, `amount2`, `amount3` without calculating `get_amount1`, `get_amount2`, `get_amount3` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr` within single serializer instance:

```
def get_amount1(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    if getattr(self, 'amount1', None):
        return self.amount1
    self.amount1 = 5
    return self.amount1

def get_amount2(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    if getattr(self, 'amount2', None):
        return self.amount2
    self.amount2 = 10
    return self.amount2

def get_amount3(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    if getattr(self, 'amount3', None):
        return self.amount3
    self.amount3 = 15
    return self.amount4

def get_total(self,obj):
    return self.get_amount1(obj) +self.get_amount2(obj)+self.get_amount3(obj)
```

Or as @Willem-Van-Onsem mentioned in comment [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for more broad caching:

```
@lru_cache
def get_amount1(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    return 5

@lru_cache
def get_amount2(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    return 10

@lru_cache
def get_amount3(self,obj):
    """very large calculation here"""
    return 15
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the `obj` can be different in *every* call (by *reusing* the serializer). So you might want to use an `lru_cache` instead.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, `getattr` only helps within single serializer instance. `lru_cache` is more common solution.